# How to decode a base64 xml file with key

Tags: java, encryption, base64

I have to decode a xml file encoded base64 with a key (1234) in java, I have been searching but I can't find a method to decode it with a key.

[EDIT]

The encrypted file has a zml extension (the application changes the extension from xml to zml when it's encrypted). I opened the zml file with 7zip and the software ask me for the password, I used the 1234 and i could see the decoded file.

The question is how can i simulate the same process with java, somehow 7zip knows that the file was encrypted in base64 and later ask my for the password.

How could you do that with java?

Best regards.

Comment: In the following post there are some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: There's no such thing as a "key" for base64 encoding.

Comment: Presumably you would base64 decode your data to a buffer then use the key to decrypt it to output the cleartext xml.  You need to ask the people who provided you with the data.

Comment: I'm going to ask them about that, It was weird not finding any clue about key implementation with the base64 methods.

Comment: Mamy encryption algorithms output look like Base64 data.  The output encrypted outputs use ASCII characters.  So you probably don't have Base64 data but instead just encrypted file.