# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int while converting String to bytesArray

Tags: android, arrays, base64

I am retrieving a base64 string from database and then trying to convert it to bytes array. I get the following error in the second step :

> Process: com.streamsystem.bomarecompany.syncadapter, PID: 23085
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: 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`

and here's is my code for te conversion:

```
 temp = image.split(",");
                bytesArray = new byte[temp.length];
                for (String item: temp) {
                    bytesArray[index] = Byte.parseByte(item);
                    index++;
                }
```

How can I fix that please (sorry for the base64 code ) , thanks !

Comment: why are you splitting image into commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of java 8 there is official API for base64 encoding and decoding, this code should work:

```
import android.util.Base64;

byte[] bytesArray = Base64.decode(item, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

See more here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15646871/5529621

Comment: thanks for you help , i used your code and i got a result of the conversion of my base64  = [B@8f94a5 , is it true ?