# Encoding a URI for a RESTful Service

Tags: javascript, json, rest, encoding

I am trying to call a java GET RESTful service with an email address from Ionic 2 (javascript). It works fine, however when I add a dot (e.g. .com) to the email address it looses all the characters from the dot when it reaches the service.

How do I encode the URI in order to send an email address to the service please?

I am using:

`'/list/email/' + encodeURIComponent(email)`

but if the email address is: `email@domain.com`, it reaches the service as `email@domain`.

I have tried:

`'/list/email/' + email`

`'/list/email/' + encodeURI(email)`

`'/list/email/' + encodeURIComponent(email)`

all give the same result

Thanks

Comment: in which format should the email address be endocoded?

Comment: Is dot reaches the server ??

Comment: The dot does not reach the server. only the characters before the dot

Comment: Sorry Lukas, I don't understand your question. I want the email address to come out on the server the same way it is enetered on the client.

Comment: This . might be considered as page ending like .jsp or .php  .asp ....might be..I am not sure

Comment: what if you try to base64 encode that string and decode it on the server? or is that no option?

Comment: Yes, that's why I think it needs to be encoded somehow

Comment: I second Lukas base64 will be much better

Comment: I will give base64 a try...thanks

Comment: no problem here to help

Comment: But why did things after . were discarded by the server ...Does anybody knows ??????

Comment: I think the Server thinks its someone is requesting a File and removes the ".".

Comment: if I do `/email/something` it works. but `/something/email` doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You could try to encode your E-Mail Address to a Base64 String.

```
var encodedData = window.btoa("test@test.com"); // encode a string
var decodedData = window.atob(encodedData); // decode the string
```

That's how you can decode a Base64 String on the Server

```
byte[] valueDecoded= Base64.decodeBase64(bytesEncoded);
System.out.println("Decoded value is " + new String(valueDecoded));
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Can I decode the string in java on the server?

Comment: Of course you can decode the string on server, question on that has been answered on this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Answer (score 1):

The FIX is simple. Just add a '/' on the end of the url

```
return this.http.get(this.BASE_URI + '/list/email/' + email + '/')
```

Comment: Ohh that was way simple then imagination

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
/somepath/{variable:.+}
```

Comment: Hi Van, thanks for the answer, but I don't understand. I am doing this in a javascript function, and the syntax you use doesn't make sense to me?