# How to convert PDDocument to Base64 String in Java?

Tags: java, base64, pdfbox

How to convert PDDocument (the pdf document contains words and images, if it is possible) to a Base64 string?

Comment: Do you want to encode the whole file or just the human-readable text inside it?

Comment: If you want to save the PDF to a byte array, just call `doc.save(baos);` with `baos` being a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. And from there you can convert to base64.

Comment: I want to encode whole file in format from pdf (PDDocument) to String Base64...

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer assumes that you are using jdk8 or higher, if not, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/).

```
import java.util.Base64;

...

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(baos);
String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
doc.close(); // don't forget to close your document
```

Comment: the same for Java 7