# I want to upload file without using multipart in spring boot, would be great if I could get you valuable suggestions on this

Tags: spring-boot, file

Shall I remove this from application.properties

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
```

What should be my approach towards this file upload without using multipart?

This way, I'm able to uploading file using where I'm using multipart.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dog/create/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public JsonNode dogCreation(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, @RequestParam(value = "picture", required = false) MultipartFile multipartFile,
                                @PathVariable("name") String name) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        String DOG_IMAGES_BASE_LOCATION = "resource\\images\\dogImages";

        try {
            File file = new File(DOG_IMAGES_BASE_LOCATION);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dog = dogService.getDogByName(name);
        if (dog == null) {
            if (!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
                String multipartFileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                String format = multipartFileName.substring(multipartFileName.lastIndexOf("."));
                try {
                    Path path = Paths.get(DOG_IMAGES_BASE_LOCATION + "/" + name + format);
                    byte[] bytes = multipartFile.getBytes();
                    File file = new File(path.toString());
                    file.createNewFile();
                    Files.write(path, bytes);
                    if (file.length() == 0) {
                        response = utility.createResponse(500, Keyword.ERROR, "Image upload failed");
                    } else {
                        String dbPath = path.toString().replace('\\', '/');
                        dog = new Dog();
                        dog.setName(name);
                        dog.setPicture(dbPath);
                        dog = dogService.dogCreation(dog);
                        response = utility.createResponse(200, Keyword.SUCCESS, "Image upload successful");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return objectMapper.readTree(response.toString());
    }
```

I want to do it without using multipart, what would you suggest?

This is what I've done till now to solve this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dog/create/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public JsonNode dogCreation(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, @RequestParam("picture") String picture,
                                @PathVariable("name") String name) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        String DOG_IMAGES_BASE_LOCATION = "resource\\images\\dogImages";

        try {
            File file = new File(DOG_IMAGES_BASE_LOCATION);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        dog = dogService.getDogByName(name);
        if (dog == null) {
            if (!picture.isEmpty()) {
                String dogPicture = picture;
                byte[] encodedDogPicture = Base64.encodeBase64(dogPicture.getBytes());
                String format = dogPicture.substring(picture.lastIndexOf("."));
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return objectMapper.readTree(response.toString());
    }
```

[image: request body picture is given below]

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available on internet. you can refer any of them and in case you face any issue, ask a question on stackoverflow with your code snippet.

Comment: @Smile, Have upload code, would be great if you could suggest something. Haven't uploaded Service and repository portion, uploaded the controller portion only.

Comment: Why do you not want to use multipart?  That is the standard way of uploading files with http.  Otherwise maybe upload using websockets or encode the file to base64 and do a normal post?

Comment: @DaafVader It's a requirement that I'm facing

Answer (score 0):

I just have to say that this should probably only be used as a workaround.

On your frontend, convert the file to base64 in js:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function(evt) {
   console.log(evt.target.result);
   //do POST here - something like this:
   $.ajax("/upload64", {
     method: "POST",
     contentType: "application/text"
     data: evt.target.result
   }
};
```

On the server with an example of a decoder - more decoding options here [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;


@PostMapping("/upload64")
public String uploadBase64(@RequestBody String payload){
   BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
   byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);
   //use your bytes
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error 
"Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String': no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

Comment: Make sure your contentType header is set correctly in your post request. Edited with example above.

Comment: Key --> Content-Type 
Value --> application/json

Comment: Sir, how can I get binary data from post request that's been passed from postman?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  That seems like a completely new question though...