# Decode response from API

Tags: java, rest, okhttp

I want to implement a basic example using OkHttpClient. In my case I want to make Rest requests to
https://data.brreg.no/rofs/od/rofs/stottetildeling/search?language=nob&mottakerOrgnr=987&fraDato=2016-11-20

In order to get public data. More information:

https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/docs/index.html#_oversikt
https://www.brreg.no/produkter-og-tjenester/apne-data/register-offentlig-stotte/api

I implemented this code:

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://data.brreg.no/rofs/od/rofs/stottetildeling/search?language=eng")
        .get()
        .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println(response.body().string());
```

But I get this result:

```
IGVsbGVyIGF2Z2lmdHNmb3JkZWwiLCJzdG90dGVpbnN0cnVtZW50RnJpdGVrc3QiOm51bGwsInN0b3R0ZW1vdHRha2VyU3RvcnJlbHNlIjoiTGl0ZW4gb2cgTWVsbG9tc3RvciIsIm5hZXJpbmciOiI0MS4yIiwibmFlcmluZ0Jlc2tyaXZlbHNlIjoiT3BwZsO4cmluZyBhdiBieWduaW5nZXIiLCJmeWxrZXNudW1tZXIiOjE4LCJmeWxrZSI6Ik5vcmRsYW5kIiwic3RvdHRlZ2l2ZXJPcmdhbmlzYXNqb25zbnVtbWVyIjoiOTc0NzYxMDc2Iiwic3RvdHRlZ2l2ZXJOYXZuIjoiU0tBVFRFRVRBVEVOIiwic3RvdHRlZ2l2ZXJzUmVmZXJhbnNlIjpudWxsLCJ1bG92bGlnU3RvdHRlIjpudWxsfSx7InRpbGRlbGluZ0lkIjoi............
```

Looks like I have to configure the encoding properly in order to read the data. what is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: I tried with Java 8 Maven project with dependency com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1. I used the same code in your post and I see data printed in console

Comment: I use Java 11 with Coretto JVM

Comment: Just an observation: That looks like a Base 64 encoded string, which decodes to JSON (containing what appears to be Norwegian text). See [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html).

Comment: ok, how I can decode it to readable text?

Comment: You can research that question - for example: [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java). But I think it's probably better to figure out why it's encoded that way in the first place (i.e. fix the root cause problem, rather than using a workaround). I'd be surprised if the response is _supposed_ to arrive that way - but maybe that is correct. Can these responses contain binary data, such as images?

Comment: Is it possible to configure the encoding into OkHttpClient?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. But it sounds like you have a new (and much more specific) question you can now research - and a new question you can ask, if you need to. (I'd be surprised if this has not already been asked and answered on SO.)

Comment: Can you please check what output you get for below code snippet? 
MediaType mediaType = response.body().contentType();
System.out.println("Media Type: " + mediaType.type());
System.out.println("Media Subtype: " + mediaType.subtype());

Comment: I get `Media Type: application
Media Subtype: json`

Comment: Media Type and Subtype looks good. I too get the same. Wondering why you don't get the json output string. One last try, can you pls share the dependency tree. If you use Maven, can you please share the output of this - mvn dependency:tree

Comment: I use Gradle: https://pastebin.com/9ajc534X